# How do I correctly take the conditional probabilities involving unions?

Tags: probability

I am having trouble figuring out how to take these probabilities:
$$P(A \cup B | C \cup D)$$
$$P(A | C \cup D)$$

Also, I wanted to confirm that
$$P(A \cup B | C ) = P(A | C) + P(B | C )$$

Thank you! And sorry if this question has been answered before, it's hard to search something that has union symbol on google and the similar answers on here didn't really answer my questions.

Edit: I forgot to mention that A and B are independent!

Comment: No, the last statement isn't true, any more than $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ is true.

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that! I was thinking about it in the setting of my problem in which A and B are independent!

Comment: That *still* would not be correct.  $\mathsf P(A\cup B\mid C)=\mathsf P(A\mid C)+\mathsf P(B\mid C)$ means that $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ are **disjoint** -- *not* that they are independent.

Comment: Oh my goodness, sorry, I think that is what I meant! I have not taken a probability class in over two years, so I completely forgot they were separate! Disjoint means they cannot happen at the same time right?

Answer (score 0):

Actually $P(A\cup B|C)=P(A|C)+P(B|C)-P(A\cap B|C)\space\space\space$(if $A$ and $B$ aren't disjoint)

Now as per Bayes Theorem,
$$P(A|C\cup D)=\dfrac{P(A)P(C\cup D|A)}{P(C\cup D)}=\dfrac{P(A).[P(C|A)+P(D|A)-P(C\cap D|A)]}{P(C)+P(D)-P(C\cap D)}$$

You can similarly find $P(A\cup B|C\cup D)$